# How to share large data sets to third party data consumers/services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, data-sharing

Lets assume I have a client who has plethora of data related to railways(Signals, tracks, train timings, hazard. offers etc). There are various internal department in railways which wants that data. Just like various weather websites get data from weather department and show that data on their website. Similar is my requirement that I want to share the data securely with other department and services. I want to look at best method to share the data to other services as quickly as possible when the data is available.

Possible Solution

**API based:** Create API for each department and share them data via API. This has its own pros and cons. This is something which came to my mind but we would have to create lot go API's I was looking if Azure and AWS has any other service which can do the same.

**Azure based solution:** I am looking for help in this if Azure and services it provides can help. Service bus, Event Grid, Event Hub  etc can these be of any use?.

**AWS based solution:** Is there any service in AWS which can help here?. I dont have much exposure to AWS.

Any other solution ?

I have a fair idea that this could be built using API's but I am looking if I can get this done using cloud platforms like Azure and AWS> This will help in better integration of the product and can scale.

Comment: It all depends on the data and the desired access (patterns). On AWS you could use LakeFormation, Glue, S3, Redshift, a "normal" database, ... or just an API Gateway with a Lambda.

Comment: So API's I something I am inclined to but I was looking for similar functionality on Azure and AWS. In Azure I found Azure data share.